# translation done incorrectly in opengl

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

i am making a 2d game using opengl in android. I have a square textured sprite which i intend to use it as a bouncing ball.
The problem i am facing is regarding the translation of the sprite. I am using a single model matrix as a uniform of my vertex shader. i update that matrix before rendering each of the sprites. Is THIS the right method to do so??

I want to make the ball accelerate by using gravity effect but it only translates with constant speed.

Here is the update function of the sprite class :-

```
    public Ball(int textureID) {
    texture = textureID;
    //Stores location of the center of the ball
    location = new Vector(300,350);
    //The velocity of ball
    speed = new Vector(0, 0);
    //gravity acceleration
    accel = new Vector(0, 2);
    //Geometry of ball
    rect = new Geometry.Rectangle(new Geometry.Point(location.getI() - RADIUS,location.getJ() - RADIUS, 0), 2*RADIUS, 2*RADIUS);
    //Builder class to create vertex coordinates
    builder = new ObjectBuilder(ObjectBuilder.RECTANGLE2D, true);
    builder.generateData(rect, 0);
    //Vertex Array holds the coordinates
    vertexArray = new VertexArray(builder.vertexData);
}

public void update(float[] modelMatrix) {
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    location.addVector(speed);
    Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, speed.getI(), speed.getJ(), 0);
    accel.setJ(1);
    speed.addVector(accel);
    accel.setI(-(0.3f * speed.getI()));
}
```

My Vertex shader :-

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TextureCoordinates;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main() {
v_TextureCoordinates = a_TextureCoordinates;
gl_Position = u_Matrix * u_ModelMatrix * a_Position;
}
```

My OnDrawFrame Function :-

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {    
   textureShaderProgram.useProgram();
   ball.update(modelMatrix);
   textureShaderProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, modelMatrix);
   ball.bindData(textureShaderProgram);
   ball.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update function in wrong. You translate your `modelMatrix` by speed instead of location.

```
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, speed.getI(), speed.getJ(), 0);
```

You probably want something like:

```
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, location.getI(), location.getJ(), 0);
```

Your speed basicly functions as location now, which is incremented each update:

```
accel.setJ(1);
speed.addVector(accel);
accel.setI(-(0.3f * speed.getI()));
```

`speed` is initially `(0, 0)` and is incremented by `accel` every update, which will always be `(0, 1)` as `-(0.3f * 0) = 0`.

Therefore your object moves with a constant speed of (0, 1).

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. 
Btw is my method of translating the object right?? 
I am passing this model matrix to the uniform before each rendering of the object.

Comment: Do i have to give every object their own model matrix or just changing the one can do it

Comment: It is A right way to do it. You can just change that one matrix every time (however, you still have send it as a uniform to the shader every time you change it), however I always prefer keeping a model matrix for every object.